# Set up a testing classes dependency upon another module in a maven project

Tags: maven

A maven project has a core module and a sql module. The sql module's test classes should extend some of the core module test classes. What needs to be done in the sql module pom.xml  to set up that dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: the way is to add a test-jar with "test" scope.

```
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
```

So here is the full dependency for my case

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a test jar out of your core module, and then add it as a test scoped dependency in your sql module.

Add the below plugin declaration to the build/plugins section of your core module's pom file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now add this test jar as a dependency in your sql module

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.coderplus.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>coremodule</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```